# Keep the expandable div open after the page post back

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div in an ASP.Net page. Inside that div is a form that contains `asp:dropdownlists` that conditionally change other fields, thus requiring PostBack. When the postback occurs, the expandable div returns to its collapsing state of not being visible. I want the expanded div to remain open after the value is selected from the dropdown list.

Below is the `jQuery` which is used in expand and collapse div:

```
$('.toggler1').live('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().children().toggle();     
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.toggled_content').slideToggle(); 
    $(this).closest(".toggleHolder").next(".hiddenText").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: you need to fire jQuery after postback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hidden input to your form and give it a distinguishable ID or Class. This will post true if the div is expanded. Give it an initial value of "false" if you like.

Then add the line:

```
$('.toggler1').live('click', function () {
    $('#MyHiddenInputNamedBetter').val('true'); // Add this line
```

Then in your .NET code you do something similar to (I've got a VB background):

```
<% If isPostBack AndAlso CBool(Request.Form('MyHiddenInputNamedBetter')) Then %>
    <script>
        $('.toggler1').parent().children().toggle(); // .... etc.
    </script>
<% End If %>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is correct but can you please suggest me in the case of multiple expandable div. There are about 5-8 blocks on one page and in each block there is one drop down list and one expandable div.

Comment: In that case you could store a comma delimited list of numbers that are open, for example if 1, 3 and 5 were open then it would store `1,3,5`. Then convert it to an array like `Request.Form('MyHiddenInputNamedBetter').Split(","c)`. Then you'll loop through them: `For Each intInput As Integer In arrInputs` (or whatever your array is declared as) and then write out `$('.toggler<%=intInput%>').parent()....`